# How can I integrate OpenStack instances in my local network?

Tags: networking, openstack, local-network, floating-ip

How can I integrate OpenStack instances in my local network? I have Devstack Kilo running on a single Ubuntu VM that has its own IP different than the physical host. I assigned as floating IPs a set of IPs from the local network. But I cannot ping neither the external network, nor the local network from the instances.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the network on the devstack host to do ip and arp forwarding. This ususally works:

```
sudo bash
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This is for an Ubuntu host running devstack - your distro may be a little different, but the ideas are the same.

I wrote a post about doing this a while back. It's for Havana, but the principles are the same:
https://barakme.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/openstack-in-a-box-setting-up-devstack-havana-on-your/